# How to select all value present at the same time delete the content and enter new value using selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer-11

I need to perform actions - double click on an element and select all value present at the same time, then delete the content and enter new value.

below i have implemented the same. It performs double click on the element but not perform `Keys.Control + "a"`, delete and change value

```
IWebElement AmountTextBoxElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("id_to_find"));
Actions act= new Actions(driver);
act.DoubleClick(AmountTextBoxElement).Build().Perform();
WaitingPeriod.SleepMedium();
AmountTextBoxElement.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
WaitingPeriod.SleepMedium();
AmountTextBoxElement.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
WaitingPeriod.SleepMedium();
AmountTextBoxElement.SendKeys("2323609");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using ActionBuilder

```
Actions action = new Actions(); 
action.MoveToElement(AmountTextBoxElement);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("A").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

Comment: this will double click the element and change value                         
 Actions act = new Actions(driver);
 act.DoubleClick(AmountTextBoxElement).Build().Perform();
 act.MoveToElement(AmountTextBoxElement);
 WaitingPeriod.SleepMedium();         act.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys("2345").KeyUp(Keys.Control).Perform();